# oracle CRUD frontend

Tags: oracle, rest

We have an existing system using Oracle DB and several applications working on/off it using JDBC/ODBC etc. For an additional interface for CRUD operations I am looking at a web based front-end. I dont see a whole of ideas in this areas, maybe  because the ORacle DB is mostly enterprise and probably means the enterprises building their own custom apps?

Using the Oracle REST API services, build a front end using Angular/JS. This eliminates any need for oracle specific server side logic and almost ORacle independent. Are there any frameworks / opensource tools that fall in this area?

Please let me know any comments / feedback on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there aren't really any options like this specifically for Oracle databases. You might be better off going with a desktop solution, of which there are many.

There is a web UI called "[H2 Console](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html)" which claims to work with any JDBC connection. I have used this with MySql before with great success but have not tried it with Oracle.

> The H2 Console application lets you access a database using a browser. This can be a H2 database, or another database that supports the JDBC API.

If you want something more 'user friendly' then as far as I know there are no existing solutions for this. You will probably have to build your own or educate your users on SQL.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question - the UIs I am talking about require you to type in SQL statements to view results. They then allow editing of individual cells or rows without having to write the SQL yourself, but the initial query requires the user to type in a SQL command.

Comment: Yes, we are not looking at a admin like interface, It should be a html / browser based to view and update records

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to find something that does what you want. But try the H2 interface... you never know. To be honest it's quite handy for developers even if it doesn't work for your original purpose.